# Rails 3.2.1 - Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I'm brand new to rails and am trying to dive in to my first project on my Mac, but am running in to an issue when I run Rake -T inside my project's root dir:

```
Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources
Run 'bundle install' to install missing gems.
```

After I run 'bundle install' I get:

```
Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./rake
```

But I still get the same error when I call Rake again. My gemfile lists rake as:

```
gem 'rake', '0.9.2.2'
```

If I run 'bundle list' I can see:

```
  * rake (0.9.2.2)
```

I've looked at other posts on stackoverflow and google, but none of the solutions have worked for me. I'd also really appreciate any background on what's going on here, for instance, should rake be installed in to the project directory like this?
I'm not sure what else I should include to help troubleshoot?

Thank you!

Comment: You've run `bundle install rake` at some point. Go into `.bundle/config` and remove the option containing "rake"

Comment: I removed the line "BUNDLE_PATH: rake" and now I get this error: "Could not find i18n-0.6.0 in any of the sources", even after I've run 'bundle install' again. If I run 'bundle show i18n' I get: '/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/i18n-0.6.0' and 'bundle show rake' gives: '/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to https://rvm.io
instal rvm, rvm install 1.9.3, rvm use 1.9.3 --default
then you can manage your gems through rvm
It is the best solution to manage your gems.

Comment: because of insane dependency problems that drove people nuts and made them really need a Ruby Version Manager solution.

Comment: I thought Gem was the package manager? Now I'm getting: rake aborted!
dlopen(/Users/slowfib/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/slowfib/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/slowfib/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle

Comment: Wow! I can't believe how painful installing Rails was on Mac. Wish all this was easier. Finally solved this error by running: sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib

Comment: For mysql http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/ after installing just brew install mysql

Comment: Thanks Alisher, I'll note that for next time.

Answer (score 1):

please check if rvm is configured correctly - read about .rvmrc and setup_and_load_paths.rb http://blog.ninjahideout.com/posts/the-path-to-better-rvm-and-passenger-integration, also check  lines at your nginx(i suppose you use it, cause, i just had exactly same problem) configs passenger_root and passenger_ruby (this one should include smth like output of which ruby + @your_gem_set) 
good luck

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Gem install rake` ?

Bundle will not install anything to your path I do not think but you may also get it working by `bundle exec rake`. If that doesn't work, try `bundle exec rake -v0.9.2.2.2`

I don't fully understand how bundle works either as running Rails commands on my computer runs Rails 3.2.2 while the bundle runs Rails 3.1.1

Comment: No joy. "gem install rake" said "1 rake installed", but didn't work. Also tried "bundle exec rake" which gave back "Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources. Run 'bundle install' to install missing gems." Thanks for the idea.